# Hilfe bei der Analyse von „Der Musikant“ (Eichendorff)

Tags: meaning-in-context, poetry, literature

In folgendem Gedicht Eichendorffs (von Hugo Wolf als gleichnamiges Lied „Der Musikant“ großartig vertont) verstehe ich den folgenden Text nicht:

> **Manche Schöne macht wohl Augen,
>
>   Meinet, ich gefiel’ ihr sehr,**
>   Wenn ich nur was wollte taugen,
>   So ein armer Lump nicht wär.

Was den Numerus anbelangt: *Manche Schöne* scheint mir in der Einzahl zu stehen. Ist eine der folgenden Interpretationen richtig?

1. Der Text in Fettschrift ist (bis auf meinen schlechten Stil) äquivalent zu

   > *Manche Schönen machen wohl Augen,
   >
   >   Meinen, ich gefiel’ ihnen sehr,* (…)
2. *Manch* deutet auf Häufigkeit hin. Das heißt, *manch* bedeutet eher, dass dies, was der Abschnitt beschreibt, nicht nur ein einziges Mal passiert ist. Etwa:

   > **Öfters** *macht eine Schöne wohl Augen,
   >
   >   Meint, ich gefiel’ ihr sehr,* (…)

   Zum Schluss: Warum hat man dann für das gleiche Subjekt *macht* (einzeln), wobei *meinet* schein in der Mehrzahl zu sein?

Den gesamten Text findet man etwa auf [Projekt Gutenberg.](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/joseph-von-eichendorff-gedichte-4294/151)

Comment: _Meinet_ = _meint_, 3. Person Singular.

Comment: Das zweite "e" in "meinet" dient nur dazu, ein regelmäßiges Versmaß einzuhalten. Außerhalb von Gedichten ist diese Form heute unüblich.

Comment: Ich meine, du meinest, er/sie/es meinet, wir meinen, ihr meinet, sie meinen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wenn ich das in einigermaßen aktuelles Deutsch übertragen müsste, würde ich wohl folgendes sagen:

> So manch hübsche Frau hat mich schon angeschaut,
>   und gedacht,
>   dass ich ihr schon ganz gut gefallen würde,
>   wenn ich es nur ein bisschen zu etwas gebracht hätte
>   und nicht so ein armer Kerl wäre...

Im Detail:

> Manche Schöne macht wohl Augen

*Manche Schöne*: Von allen schönen Frauen eine nicht unbeträchtliche Zahl (*so manche*).
*macht wohl Augen*: "Augen machen" sagt man heute noch für "staunen". In diesem Fall wird es eher so was bedeuten wie "einen Blick riskieren" oder "betrachten/anschauen".

> Meinet, ich gefiel’ ihr sehr,

*Meinet*: alte lyrische Form von "meint". Also: manche schöne Frau meint...
*ich gefiel´ ihr sehr*: ich gefiele ihr (neuer: Ich würde ihr sehr gefallen)

> Wenn ich nur was wollte taugen,

*wollte XYZ*: Alte Form des Konjunktiv. Man hätte auch schreiben können "wenn ich nur was taugte"
*etwas taugen*: Alter Ausdruck für "es zu etwas gebracht haben", "etwas wert sein", "etwas aus sich gemacht haben", "sozial akzeptabel sein", "gängigen moralischen Werten entsprechen", "vorzeigbar sein". *nichts taugen* wurde häufig (wie im Kommentar unten erwähnt) für Menschen verwendet, die einen unsteten Lebenswandel pflegten, faul waren, eventuell nicht gesellschaftlich akzeptabel waren (vgl. *Taugenichts*).

Also: Ich würde so manch schöner Frau gefallen, wenn ich es nur zu was gebracht hätte

> So ein armer Lump nicht wär

Das kann man fast so lassen. Statt "Lump" würde man heute "Kerl" sagen. Früher auch "Taugenichts" oder "Rumtreiber".

Comment: Gute Analyse, nur eine Kleinigkeit: "Taugen" ist nicht nur, vielleicht nicht einmal in erster Linie materiell gemeint, sondern beinhaltet auch eine moralische und soziale Komponente. Ein Mensch, der "nichts taugt", also ein "Taugenichts", ist mindestens unstet und nicht fleißig, vermutlich auch untreu und unehrlich. Dass er damit nicht reich wird, ist eher ein Nebeneffekt.

Comment: Danke für diesen zusätzlichen Hinweis! Ich werde die Antwort ggf. dahingehend erweitern.

Answer (score 8):

**Manche Schöne** bedeutet **manch eine aus der Menge der Schönen**. Oder, als Reaktion of den Comment, **eine jede aus einer Untermenge der Menge der Schönen**.

Manche Schöne ist Einzahl und betrachtet jede Einzelne aus der Menge der Schönen, auf die folgende Aussage zutrifft: sie macht wohl Augen, meint, ich gefiele ihr sehr.

Die Aussage **manche Schöne** beinhaltet, dass es ein nicht unbeträchtlicher Teil der Gesamtmenge der Schönen ist.

Und wie in den Kommentaren bereits gesagt wurde, ist **meinet** eine poetische Form von **meint**, also 3. Person Singular, um das Versmass (in diesem Fall Trochäus) einzuhalten.